# Question about type conversion of different data types in integer or real number in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, types, integer

I'm learning Java with Eclipse, but I have a question about data types.

Among the error messages of the byte type, there is an error saying 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte', and to assign an integer to the long type, you must add 'L' to the end of the number. If you want to use a float type rather than a double type even for real numbers, you must add 'F' to the end of the decimal.

Do integers and real numbers check the data type of a variable and keep it int or change to another integer data type such as long after it is assigned as int and double type regardless of the size of the value and the data type specified before the variable name?

If so, if you use byte or long instead of int when writing an integer variable, the wasteful action of converting the type once occurs. Is that a very small action that can be ignored when creating a program?

I wonder if I should always keep this in mind when creating integer and float variables.

Comment: "*the wasteful action of converting the type once occurs*" Please, forget about these micro-optimizations. You're a beginner. You will have enough trouble writing something that's *correct*. You're thinking about "concerns" that will make no practical difference. Most efficiencies are made at the algorithm- or architecture-level, not at level of single statements.

Comment: "and to assign an integer to the long type, you must add 'L' to the end of the number" this isn't true: `int a = 0; long b = 0;` works just fine, as does `long b = a;`: no `L` suffix is required there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you entering the values in out code like this?

```
byte  bVal = 10;
short sVal = 10;
int   iVal = 10;
long  lVal = 10;
```

Then there is no "conversion loss", you are *just* telling the compiler how to treat the values you entered, and that you *really* know what integer size  you are using (8, 16, 32 or 64 bits). The same applies to double and float.

The compiler generates the correct byte code during the compile. No conversion happens.

More information can be found in the [Java Languange Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-PrimitiveType).

Comment: "(although the L suffix isn't strictly needed)" _None_ of the explicit conversions are needed there. https://ideone.com/G5rF0a because all of the values are compile-time constants, the compiler is able to implicitly narrow the `short` and `byte` cases; and, as you already pointed out, the compiler can implicitly widen, although that doesn't require a compile-time constant value.

Comment: @AndyTurner True, I'll update it, showing the unrequired conversions confuses more than it helps. Thanks for the input.